# MonoTouch INotifyPropertyChanged without large framework

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, observer-pattern, inotifypropertychanged

I have a monotouch application that I want to have some MVVM characteristics using INotifyPropertyChanged.

I do not want to include a MVVM framework like MvvmCross to get this working.

I could manually add an event handler to the INotifyPropertyChanging and update text fields (etc) manually, but I am looking for a generic approach that doesn't require a huge 3rd part library.

What do I need to do to get bind a text field to a "viewmodel.property"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lite version of MVVMCross which allows you to do databinding without the need for incorporating all of the MVVMCross dll's.

https://github.com/slodge/CrossLight

Comment: Seems to support Android only at the moment.

Comment: I'm really looking in to how to use the observers in monotouch.

Comment: It supports MonoTouch too - but I haven't published any samples for it.